# Is there any plugin to replace the Gendarme rules plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube

Hi all am trying to upgrade sonarqube from 4.5.6 to 5.6.6

**Current plugins:**

- Sonarqube v4.5.6
- sonar C# plugin v2.1
- sonar C# stylecop plugin  v2.1
- sonar dotnet fxcop plugin v2.1
- sonar dotnet gendarme plugin v2.1
- sonar dotnet ndeps plugin v2.1
- sonar dotnet plugin v2.1
- sonar dotnet powertool plugin v2.1
- sonar resharper plugin v2.0

**Latest plugins:**

- Sonarqube v5.6.6
- sonar resharper plugin v2.0 (same from v4.5.6)
- sonar fxcop  plugin v1.0 (replacement for the sonar dotnet fxcop plugin v2.1)

I need the replacement plugins for the above current list plugins other than the lastest plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old dotnet plugin was a kind of enabling plugin for .NET analysis. It is no longer needed. Just install the latest version of SonarC#, which calculates the basic metrics and provides a number of rules, and it will replace the "sonar C# plugin v2.1" as well as the "sonar dotnet plugin v2.1".

The NDeps, Gendarme, and StyleCop plugins are abandoned.

I've never heard of the "sonar dotnet powertool plugin" and Google doesn't seem to know about it either.

Comment: Thanks Ann Here which plugin takes Ndeps workload(metrics calculation) & which plugin has equivalent rules of the gendarme rules.

Comment: Regarding metrics, see my expansion. Regarding rules, I have no idea. You might want to take a look at the rules offered by [SonarC#](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarcsharp/rules.html). For rules you feel are missing, feel free to drop a line to the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube)

Comment: @user7014262, or better yet, drop us a line here https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues

Comment: Thanks  Ann & Valeri,  for your kind info & continuous support... Now i got the point & its suffice for me.